# Error occured during Geodatabase compressing

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

When I am doing geodatabase administration in ArcSDE on an Oracle Database, the following error pops up when I run the **compress** tool

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01000: 
maximum open cursors exceeded.

With out compressing, our database performance is coming down.What might be the error and what should be the remedy.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase opened cursors limit in oracle http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01000_maximum_open_cursors_exceeded.htm or just post all versions and move all data to FGDB, then delete all data in enterprise geodatabse, compress, and copy it again from FGDB